# How to get acces to findViewById from another class?

Tags: android, xml, class, findviewbyid

We all know you can't use static on `findViewById` so ...

The basic code is:

```
public class DiffViewFlowExample extends Activity implements OnItemClickListener {

@Override
public void onCreate() {


}

static void hereismymethod() {

}
```

How can I use a `findViewById` here? I know I can't locally but because `static` won't work then...

Oh you might say: add it as an argument,well I would,but I will call the hereismymethod from a service,and we all know that services don't like to play with stuff that is about display...

So can anybody save me?

Answer (score -1):

You shouldn't be calling method2, static or not, on an `Activity` from outside of the `Activity`. If you want to act upon your `Activity` from within the `Service`, then create a listener interface and then register your activity as a listener inside of the service. Then, when it's appropriate, have your service find the `view` and act on it. To allow the service to access the views in your `Activity`, simply make your interface method pass a reference to the `Activity`. Then, the Service can call activity.findViewById() and do whatever it wants to it.

Comment: so you want me to make a method that returns a findviewbyid...I don't really understand what you mean. And with that listener interface my head really spins right now. I'm not a very very experience coder... Can you please write a sample for me? Keep in mind I have to use that findviewbyid method in service,and I don't really know how it will work... Thank you!